# Rendering the same scene in two independent windows

Tags: qt, opengl

I am trying to renderer the same scene in two different `QOpenGLWindow`s. I don't want to duplicate memory, for this reason I am trying to use the share context but I'm not sure how it works.

I'm using the attribute `Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts` because the documentation says that It makes that every shader context will be shared between them.

However, I'm generating the VBO in one context and generating a VAO and Shader Program in each context (because it cannot be shared) but the second widget does not paint anything.

**I suppose that my problem arises because the VBO is not shared between contexts. `Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts` is not enough? Maybe I have to use `QOpenGLContext::globalShareContext()`, how could I use it?**

---

The following text explains what I am doing...

Whit the following method, I generate the Object which contains the information about the object thaat I want to paint in the scene:

```
void AEOpenGLViewer::setVertices(std::vector<Vertex> vertices, GLenum primitive) {
    makeCurrent();
    GLObject *theObject = new GLObject(vertices, primitive);
    testingObjects.push_back(theObject);
    doneCurrent();
}
```

In the constructor I generate the VBO:

```
GLObject::GLObject(std::vector<Vertex> vertices, GLenum primitiveType){
    this->vertices = vertices;
    this->primitiveType = primitiveType;

    vbo.create();
    vbo.bind();
    vbo.setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer::StaticDraw);
    vbo.allocate(vertices.data(), vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex));
    vbo.release();
}
```

About the VAO and Shader program, I generate them when I'm going to paint the GLObject:

```
void GLObject::draw(QOpenGLContext* context, const QMatrix4x4& view, const QMatrix4x4& proj){
    if (!shaderProgram.contains(context))
        setupShader(context);

    if (!shaderProgram[context]->isLinked())
        shaderProgram[context]->link();

    shaderProgram[context]->bind();
    {
        shaderProgram[context]->setUniformValue(uniformWorldToCamera, view);
        shaderProgram[context]->setUniformValue(uniformCameraToView, proj);

        //If vao does not exists, create it.
        if (!this->vao.contains(context))
            setupVAO(context);

        QOpenGLVertexArrayObject *vao = this->vao[context];
        vao->bind();

        shaderProgram[context]->setUniformValue(uniformModelToWorld, transform.toMatrix());
        glDrawArrays(primitiveType, 0, vertices.size());

        vao->release();
    }
    shaderProgram[context]->release();
}
```

Each GLObject contains, using QMap, multiple shaderPrograms and VAO, one per context:

```
class GLObject
{
public:

    ...

private:

    ...

    QMap<QOpenGLContext*, QOpenGLVertexArrayObject*> vao; //VAO cannot be shared, for this reason I will create a VAO per Widget (represent by QUuid)
    QMap<QOpenGLContext*, QOpenGLShaderProgram*> shaderProgram;

    //Private helpers
    void setupVAO(QOpenGLContext* context);
    void setupShader(QOpenGLContext* context);
};
```

Finally, the QOpenGLWidgets have a std::vector that it is copy in the different Widgets.

Comment: Please at least show some code of what you're doing. It's impossible to tell what could be wrong.

Comment: I added part of my code. Best regards.

Comment: I don't see how the VBOs are actually shared. Each GLObject seems to be carrying VBO, VAO and program.

Comment: Maybe I am doing it wrong but I am copy a std::vector<GLObject *> in each QOpenGLWidget. I did not show it in the code... sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts works perfectly, I get it to work with this attribute. I have two main problem:

- First, you have to know that the context is generated when QOpenGLWidgets will paint for the first time. It is very important because VBO must be created in a shared context. So do a QOpenGLWidget::show() first and then generate the VBO.
- Second problem was regarding state management, I was binding the QOpenGLVertexArrayObject and enabling the attribute array and setting the attribute buffer of QOpenGLShaderProgram but to do this you must to binding the VBO too... I was not doing it.

Finally, I generate a shader program and VAO per context.

Thanks.